# SFTP to remote server

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, private-key

So I'm trying to SFTP to a server that has been set up by an external company for sending shipping data.
I have a username, a host and a private key file.

I can use WinSCP on my Windows 10 Machine perfectly fine but if I try to do it from Linux I can't connect.

I'm using the following command:

```
 sftp -o "IdentityFile=key-private.ppk"  user@host
```

It then asks for a passphrase which I then copy and paste in but when doing this it just seems to fail and ask for the passphrase again until it eventually comes back with:

```
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

I've read that I may need to add something into my authorised_keys file but I'm not sure how to do this.

Also: I can't SSH to the server as it has only been set up to accept SFTP connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I may need to add something into my authorised_keys file

The company has already done that, before sending you the key. If they hadn't, you wouldn't have been able to connect via WinSCP either.

> ```
> sftp -o "IdentityFile=key-private.ppk"  user@host
> ```

Your key is in the PuTTY `.ppk` format, which OpenSSH doesn't understand. Convert it using PuTTYgen (via "Export OpenSSH key" in the menu if it's Windows, via command line if on Linux):

```
puttygen key-private.ppk -o key-private.pem -O private-openssh
```

Comment: Thank you so much - I've been looking at this for hours! (I'll mark your answer as correct but it says I have to wait 4 minutes)